# SQL 2008 Column level encryption

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption

We are looking to do Column encryption on some of our DBs.
So creating the keys and encrypting is all good.
My boss is wanting to use Vault by Hashicorp to store the keys.

So I am wondering if anyone knows how you go about exporting the keys from SQL 2008 and then store them in Vault?

Comment: Add details about how you encrypted the column data.

Comment: This is the SQL I used to create my tests.

-- Create database Key
USE D2Transfer_Master;
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password123';
GO

-- Create self signed certificate
USE D2Transfer_Master;
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate1
WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect Data';
GO

-- Create symmetric Key
USE D2Transfer_Master;
GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1 
 WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 
 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
GO

Comment: The SQL I used is too long, is there a way I can post it, so it is legible?

Comment: GitHub works, or pastebin etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are five types of keys in the heirarchy of any SQL Server column encryption. They are service master key, database master key, asymmetric key, certificate and symmetric key. SQL Server contains commands to back up the service master key, database master key and the certificate with the private key to separate password protected files. If you want to have something to preserve an asymmetric key, you can create one from a strong named key file (.snk) that already contains the key pair and save that. For the symmetric key, you will need to create it from a command, specify the key_source and identity_value and save those two values in your Vault. IF you create symmetric and asymmetric keys without saving the inputs, then you will not be able to export them. If you want to learn more about another method of securing the keys, I suggest reading about Extensible Key Management systems, which is a SQL Server enterprise edition feature. An EKM is a separate piece of hardware designed to hold the keys and perform the encryption and decryption functions.

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you for the response.
I am testing using the symmetric key process with a certificate.
What are the commands you use to back up those things you mentioned?

Comment: There is a backup certificate command documented on msdn. For the symmetric key, you will need to specify the input when you use the create symmetric key command and save it into the Vault.

Comment: Ok, so this is how I created the symmetric key for my testing:
1) Created database Master key, by password = 'my password'
2) Created self signed certificate, with a subject = 'Protect data'
3) Created my symmetric key::

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1 
 WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 
 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
GO

So what out of that would I put into Vault?

Comment: An example would be: CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY #MarketingXXV   
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128,  
KEY_SOURCE   
     = 'The square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the sides',  
IDENTITY_VALUE = 'Pythagoras'  
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Marketing25;  If you don't specify those parameters, then the system will generate them for you.

Comment: Ah, ok.
So create that and whatever info I supply to key_source and identity_value
I will need to give to my Vault to hold the same?
Once that is done, can I drop the symmetric key from the DB?
Or it has to stay in place?

Comment: Also, what is Key_Source?

Comment: Once the key is created, then you will use it for column encryption
KEY_SOURCE ='pass_phrase'
Specifies a pass phrase from which to derive the key.
IDENTITY_VALUE ='identity_phrase'
Specifies an identity phrase from which to generate a GUID for tagging data that is encrypted with a temporary key.
This article will help break it down:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2009/03/30/sql-server-encryptbykey-cryptographic-message-description/.